# Splitting a table into two join tables

Tags: mysql, database, insert-into

Right now I have a mysql database with a table `userphone(id, phone, type,userid)` and I'd like to split it into two tables, `phone(id,phone,type)` and `user_phone(id,user_id,phone_id)`.

I'm doing this because I'm going to have other things that also refer to phone numbers, and they ought to be all stored in one table. (e.g. I'll also be adding a `company_phone(id,company_id,phone_id)` join table to join companies with their phone numbers).

Is there any good, efficient way of doing this? I've added the new tables, but am not sure of the best approach for populating them.

I can add all the phones from `userphone` into the `phone` table with something like

```
INSERT INTO phone(phone,type) SELECT phone,type FROM userphone;
```

but that doesn't add an entry into the new `user_phone` table for each phone.

Is there any way to `INSERT INTO` two different tables at once? (from research, I know there isn't, but I can't figure out how else to accomplish this...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not creating the phone table with the user_id initially and drop the column after you have the user_phone_table ready so you can link back phone_id to user_id?

Comment: That would work for how I described the situation above, but then I need to add the phone numbers from companyphone, which is a very similar situation and I wouldn't want to add both columns (although I guess it's a possibility)

Comment: Don't see the issue at all. You will get rid of the unneeded columns afterwards, the important thing is that you won't risk data inconsistency when setting up your tables. I think AJP's solution has the potential of creating inconsistencies by joining tables using phone numbers. I personally wouldn't use that approach.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. AJP's could cause an issue if there are duplicate phone numbers for some reason (because even if there are duplicate numbers, we want the correspondance 1-1 so that we can cascade delete). The more I think about it, the more I like your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the table user_phone as

   ```
   insert into phone(phone,type,user_id)
   select phone,type,user_id from userphone
   ```
2. Create your table user_phone as

   ```
   insert into user_phone (user_id,phone_id)
   select user_id,id from phone
   ```
3. `alter table phone drop column user_id`

Answer (score 0):

first:

INSERT INTO phone(phone,type) SELECT phone,type FROM userphone;

second:

select u.USER_ID, p.phone_ID
from userPhone u
INNER JOIN Phone p
    ON u.phone = p.phone
    and u.type = p.type

Comment: add Distinct in the select your result will not have duplicate. unless userPhone has duplicate than you will have inconsistancy in new table.